# symfony: trying to add a field from another model in a backend list. Inner join

Tags: symfony1

I have created an inner join criteria to show a list of elements in the backend.

This are my models:

```
  user:
    name:  { type: varchar(255) }
    age:   { type: integer }

  article:
    title:        { type: varchar(255) }
    content:      { type: varchar(255) }
    user_id:      { type: varchar(255) }
```

and this is my generator.yml (a part) of the article module:

```
  list:
    peer_method:  getArticles
    display: [title, content, age]
```

And this is the method getArticles():

```
public static function getArticles()
{
    $con = Propel::getConnection();
    $sql = "select * from article LEFT JOIN user ON article.user_id = user.id";
    $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);    


    $result = $stmt->execute();
    $articles = self::populateObjects($stmt);

    return $articles;

}
```

As you can see I want to show the column corresponding to the "age" field, so when I try to show the list of articles an error that says something like "The method Articles::getAge() is not defined".

So I think I should create the method Articles::getAge(), but.. what should i write inside? A new criteria that retrieves the user object corresponding to the value of the field user_id of the article? Or maybe am i wrong with any other stuff?

sf 1.4/propel

Regards

Javi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes:

```
class Articles
{
  public function getAge()
  {
    return $this->getUser()->getAge();
  }
}
```

or similar code to retrieve the value based on your related model - I use Doctrine normally, but from my hazy Propel memory I think the above should work :-)